# How to get postname in custom page?

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I'm adding custom pages in WordPress and trying to handle WordPress with my own CMS.

I'm using all WordPress' hooks to manage all these things. Now, I can make a custom post saying "a new album" but I don't know how to give a post name to it.

The database entry of `post_name` in the `wp_posts` table remains blank now as I don't know what to put there.

Comment: are you using wp_insert_post?

Comment: @birgire: Thanks for reply. It works but there is one problem. It repeats post_name, but that should not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reply to both of you.
I tried to use only `sanitize_title` function but it repeats when I want to add the same name post so I did something like below in my custom commands:

```
$post_name1 = sanitize_title($_POST['subcategory']); 
$post_name2 = wp_unique_post_slug($post_name1, $_POST['idofalbum'], 'publish', 'album', 0);
```

`$post_name1` gives me title with dashes and `$post_name2` gives me unique slug which I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sanitize_title() on the page title:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title

and then you might try something like this:

```
$my_page_title = "My page name";

$my_page_slug = sanitize_title($my_page_title); 
// or you can set the slug you want:
//$my_page_slug = "my-slug-for-this-page"; 

$my_page_content = "This is my page content";

// Create page object
$my_page = array(
  'post_title'    => $my_page_title,
  'post_name'    => $my_page_slug,
  'post_content'  => $my_page_content,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type'   => 'page',
  'post_author'   => 1,
);

// Insert the page into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_page );
```

When *updating* a page, assuming you have access to the page ID, use the following code to prevent duplicate entries:

```
$my_page = array(
  'ID'            => $my_page_id // current page ID
  'post_title'    => $my_page_title,
  'post_name'     => $my_page_slug,
  'post_content'  => $my_page_content,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type'     => 'page',
  'post_author'   => 1,
);

// Update page
wp_update_post( $my_page );
```

Note that you only need to pass changed values to wp_update_post (so if you've only changed the page content, you should pass `$my_page_content` only)